# Where should I place the series termination resistor for AVSBus?

Tags: signal, interface, signal-integrity, high-speed

I'm dealing with a AVSBus interface (like SPI, there are CLK/MOSI/MISO signals).
The CLK may run up to 25MHz, so we'd like to add series resistors on the board, as a back up if we need to tune the SI later.
My question is, where should we put these series resistors? Close to transmitters or receivers? 
And, should we use series or parallel termination method? Why?
Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a series resistor at the sending end of the clock in order to control reflections but, you do need to route the PCB track at an impedance that somewhat matches the series resistor.

Or, you can use a parallel resistor at the receiving end: -

[image]

Given that a driver may not be able to supply enough current for (say) a 50 ohm termination, a lot of folk opt for the series arrangement. There is a further option - see picture (d) below: -

[image]

It works by dealing with the high frequency content of the clock pulses (i.e. the harmonics) and terminating them correctly. This means that "C" can be quite low (maybe 100 pF or less) and DC conditions are unaffected.

At 25 MHz, you might be interested in ensuring that the 7th harmonic is properly catered for i.e. up to 175 MHz. At this frequency, the wavelength is about 1.7 metres and usually, engineers say that if track lengths are less than one tenth the wavelength, then terminators can be avoided. This means tracks can be upto 17 cm long however, electrical signals travel at about 0.6 the speed of light so, this lowers that track length to about 10 cm.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! So, for transmitter side series termination resistor, you mean that the routing trace behind this resistor should match the resistance value (say, if we choose 22 Ohm, the trace impdeance should be controlled to 22 Ohm?  That seems hard for us to "tune" the value after board is built...). And, I think these series resistor is used for eliminate the over/under shoot, right?

Comment: And, besides CLK signal, how do we usually deal with the bi-direction signals, like MOSI and MISO?

Comment: over and undershoot are caused by not making track impedance match the terminating impedance. And, the laws of physics apply to all signals equally.

Comment: @Nobody The MOSI and MISO are not bi-directional.